# How to make good visualization of time series data using tableau?

Tags: visualization, tableau

The time series data looks like this:

| Month | Count1 | Count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 100 |
| 2 | 40 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 | 17 |
| 4 | 21 | 12 |

I have tried to use area charts or basic line/bar charts to visualize the two counts based on the Month.

Are there any fancy way to visualize it? How about radial map?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should transform the month column from number to date, so Tableau would consider it as real time series. The best way would probably be using `DATEPART` function ([official guide](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.htm))

It is hard to say what visualization would be good for your purpose, without knowing the purpose and the shole context. I think that you could start from [this example](https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/vilma7846/viz/RadialTimeSeries_16138343084190/Dashboard1) (you can download the workbook) to have a great starting point.